# Add photo posts to tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr, photo

I know this is simple, but I honestly can't figure it out. Here is the relevant portion of my code

```
    <div id="right">
        {block:Posts}
            {block:Photo}
                {block:HighRes}
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                    {block:Caption}
                        {Caption}
                    {/block:Caption}
                {/block:HighRes}
            {/block:Photo}
        {/block:Posts}
    </div>
```

I just want the images to show up that I post from my dashboard. Does resolution matter? I have 5 images posted, resolutions are 414x414, 1024x683, 1600x900, 500x313, 554x554. If it's not obvious, I've never used tumblr before, nevermind make a theme.

Comment: In this case, they're going to show up if there is a high resolution version available.